# How to add version info to my powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I have a script, `test.ps1`, shown below. But I would like to be able to run: `.\test.ps1 -version` and have it return the current *version* of the script to me.

Is there a way to do this?

```bsh
<#
.SYNOPSIS

Test
  
.DESCRIPTION

 Desc

.INPUTS

 None

.OUTPUTS

  None
  
.NOTES

  Author  : me
  Version : 1.0
  Purpose : PowerShell script test
  
#>
```

This did not work.

Comment: take a look at the `*-ScriptFileInfo` cmdlets. once you have it set in a file, you can use >>> `(Test-ScriptFileInfo C:\Temp\ScriptFileInfo_Test.ps1).Version` <<< to get that info back.

Comment: PLEASE, format your code. the instructions are linked on the page you used to create your Question.

Comment: Install your code as module, then do `(Get-InstalledModule | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*ImportExcel*"}).version` where you have replaced ModuleNameHere with the name you gave your module.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to be able to run a .\test.ps1 -version and have it
>   return the current version of the script to me. Is there a way to do
>   this?

You can achieve this using a non-mandatory switch parameter to output the **NOTES** in your comment-based help.  Here's an example:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS

Test

.DESCRIPTION

Desc

.INPUTS

None

.OUTPUTS

None

.NOTES

    Author : me 
    Version : 1.0 
    Purpose : PowerShell script test

#>

param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="Display script version")]
    [switch]
    $version
)

begin {
    if ($version) {
        (Get-Help $MyInvocation.InvocationName -Full).PSExtended.AlertSet
        exit
    }
}
process { }
end { }
```

Now, when you run the following:

```
.\test1.ps1 -version
```

...you'll see your NOTES:

```
Author : me
Version : 1.0
Purpose : PowerShell script test
```

In addition, users can also see your version information (NOTES) using:

```
Get-Help .\test1.ps1 -Full
```

Hope this helps.